# Change date format from ddmmyyyy

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim DatDate As Date = Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

> The Result is 08/29/2013
>
> I Want the result as 29/08/2013
>
> Please help....

Comment: yes, your code is already formating the date to day/month/year format

Comment: Why are you formatting the date as you declare it?

Comment: "I Want the result *as a string* as 29/08/2013"

Answer (score 1):

MsgBox(Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now, Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))

Comment: Do ***not*** tell people to vote up or accept your answer, that is extremely bad ettiquette.  Also, this answer is just *wrong* -- do you think there's a month 29?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim CurDate As DateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(0) 'ex. -1 = yesterday
Dim Format As String = "d/MM/yyyy"

MsgBox(CurDate.ToString(Format))
'The Result is 29/08/2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple you have to set format to custom and set customFormat to desired format.

Here is the code.

```
Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim format As String = "dd/MM/yyyy"

    MsgBox(time.ToString(format))
```

Comment: I am really sorry I misunderstood the question I edited the answer and think this is what he needs.